# Reactjs Onchange input for function

Tags: reactjs

I have a table with multiple inputs and want my second input on each row to change the number next to it with a formula of the first row: 5-DPS(from input). I want the number to change immediately after the DPS value changes.
Is there an easy-to-understand way for someone new to react?

[image: This is the table]

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import Champions from "./components/Champions";

const Calculator = () => {
 let DPS = React.createRef();
 let TM = React.createRef();
 let CCS = React.createRef();
 let ME = React.createRef();
 let UD = React.createRef();

const Burst = 5 - DPS;
const Sustain = 5 - TM;
  const Hard = 5 - CCS;
  const Reposition = 5 - ME;
  const Offensive = 5 - UD;

  //const [DPS, setDPS] = useState("");

  return (
    <table border={1} className="inlineTable" id="table2">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td />
          <td>Pirmenybė</td>
          <td>ŽPS</td>
          <td>Staigus šaudymas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Žala</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" id="DP" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="DPS"
              id="DPS"
              ref={DPS}
              // onChange={(e) => setDPS(e.target.value)}
            />
          </td>
          <td>{Burst}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td />
          <td>Pirmenybė</td>
          <td>Sušvelninimas</td>
          <td>Išlaikymas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tvirtumas</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" id="tP" />
          </td>
          <td>
            {" "}
            <input
              type="number"
              name="TM"
              id="TM"
              ref={TM}
              //onChange={QuickChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </td>
          <td>Sustain</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td />
          <td>Pirmenybė</td>
          <td>Minkštas</td>
          <td>kietas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Minios valdymas</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" id="CCP" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="CCS"
              id="CCS"
              ref={CCS}
              // onChange={QuickChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </td>
          <td>Hard</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td />
          <td>Pirmenybė</td>
          <td>Užvedimas</td>
          <td>Perdėlioti</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mobilumas</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" id="MP" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="ME"
              id="ME"
              ref={ME}
              // onChange={QuickChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </td>
          <td>Reposition</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td />
          <td>Pirmenybė</td>
          <td>Gynybinis</td>
          <td>Agresyvus</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Naudingumas</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" id="UP" />
          </td>
          <td>
            {" "}
            <input
              type="number"
              name="UD"
              id="UD"
              ref={UD}
              //onChange={QuickChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </td>
          <td>Offensive</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
export default Calculator;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show the value for the input with value of the state. When this value changes, it will be updated with the `setDPS` function.

```js
const [DPS, setDPS] = useState(0);

<input
  type="number"
  name="DPS"
  value={DPS}
  onChange={(e) => setDPS(e.target.value)}
/>
```

If you want to depend this value and set other values, you can use a `useEffect`. When the value of `DPS` changes (inside the dependency array), the effect will run and update the value for the `burst`.

```js
const [burst, setBurst] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  setBurst(5 - DPS)
}, [DPS])
```

Or you can set all values when `DPS` changes directly in the `onChange`

```js
<input
  type="number"
  name="DPS"
  value={DPS}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setDPS(e.target.value);
    setBurst(5 - e.target.value);
  }}
/>
```